# VPython Object Revolution

Tags: rotation, translate-animation, vpython

Having to use VPython currently, and I want to make a model of the Solar System.

Currently I have all the Planets and the orbital Rings, however, the actual *orbit* is what I'm finding very difficult.

```
GlowScript 2.7 VPython
from visual import *



# Declaring Celestial Body Objects
Sun     = sphere(pos =     vec(0, 0, 0), radius =   10, color = color.yellow)
Mercury = sphere(pos =    vec(25, 0, 0), radius =    2, color =  color.green)
Venus   = sphere(pos =    vec(40, 0, 0), radius =  2.5, color =    color.red)
Earth   = sphere(pos =    vec(50, 0, 0), radius = 2.65, color =   color.blue)
Mars    = sphere(pos =    vec(70, 0, 0), radius =  2.3, color =    color.red)
Jupiter = sphere(pos =    vec(90, 0, 0), radius =    3, color = color.orange)
Saturn  = sphere(pos =   vec(105, 0, 0), radius =  2.9, color = color.orange)
Uranus  = sphere(pos = vec(117.5, 0, 0), radius =  2.9, color = color.orange)
Neptune = sphere(pos =   vec(135, 0, 0), radius =  2.8, color =   color.blue)
Pluto   = sphere(pos =   vec(165, 0, 0), radius =  1.5, color =  color.white)



# Declaring Orbital Rings of Celestial Body Objects
Mercury.ring = ring(pos = vec(0, 0, 0), axis = vec(0, 1, 0), size = vec(0.1, Mercury.pos.x * 2, Mercury.pos.x * 2))
Venus.ring   = ring(pos = vec(0, 0, 0), axis = vec(0, 1, 0), size = vec(0.1, Venus.pos.x * 2, Venus.pos.x * 2))
Earth.ring   = ring(pos = vec(0, 0, 0), axis = vec(0, 1, 0), size = vec(0.1, Earth.pos.x * 2, Earth.pos.x * 2))
Mars.ring    = ring(pos = vec(0, 0, 0), axis = vec(0, 1, 0), size = vec(0.1, Mars.pos.x * 2, Mars.pos.x * 2))
Jupiter.ring = ring(pos = vec(0, 0, 0), axis = vec(0, 1, 0), size = vec(0.1, Jupiter.pos.x * 2, Jupiter.pos.x * 2))
Saturn.ring  = ring(pos = vec(0, 0, 0), axis = vec(0, 1, 0), size = vec(0.1, Saturn.pos.x * 2, Saturn.pos.x * 2))
Uranus.ring  = ring(pos = vec(0, 0, 0), axis = vec(0, 1, 0), size = vec(0.1, Uranus.pos.x * 2, Uranus.pos.x * 2))
Neptune.ring = ring(pos = vec(0, 0, 0), axis = vec(0, 1, 0), size = vec(0.1, Neptune.pos.x * 2, Neptune.pos.x * 2))
Pluto.ring   = ring(pos = vec(0, 0, 0), axis = vec(0, 1, 0), size = vec(0.1, Pluto.pos.x * 2, Pluto.pos.x * 2))



# Infinite Loop
while 1 == 1:

    Mercury.rotate(angle = radians(360), axis = vec(Mercury.pos.y, Mercury.pos.x, 0), origin = vec(0, 0, 0))
    rate(50)

print("Error! Escaped While Loop!")
```

When I switch out the *rotate* method with `Mercury.rotate(angle = 0.0174533, axis = vec(0, Mercury.pos.x, 0), origin = vec(0, 0, 0))`, it properly rotates... yet only for a quarter of the rotation. I've read about everything to do with [this](http://vpython.org/contents/docs/rotation.html), but N/A.

After the quarter revolution, the planet sometimes decides to violently "seizure," when the angle is a larger number. It just seems like a barrier of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

You should write axis=vec(0,1,0). The axis of rotation needs to be always pointing upward.